# Existing Cluster monitoring by Hortonworks Ambari

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have a 10 node existing cluster in RHEL 6.6 which was prepared by plain apache Hadoop configuration XMLs. Now I wanted to check the cluster status by Ambari. Would it be possible to install Hortonworks Ambari just to monitor only not to install Hadoop.

Comment: Related/duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892864/how-to-deploy-ambari-for-a-exist-hadoop-cluster

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. so in a nutshell.. We don't any workaround to install ambari on existing cluster...  :(

Answer (score 1):

No, Ambari must provision the cluster it's monitoring.

Ambari is designed around a Stack concept where each stack consists of several services. A stack definition is what allows Ambari to install, manage and monitor the services in the cluster.

In order for you to use Ambari with the hadoop core that you built you would have to provide your own Ambari stack definition.

Specifically in your case your existing Hadoop installation would not have the necessary alert.json descriptors used by Ambari to provide alerts for any given service.

Comment: Anyone know if this is still true? @cjackson

Comment: Yes it's still true, this hasn't changed.